# Libertine font numbers have a different height than text

Tags: fonts, libertine, number

Currently I am writing my thesis and I want the libertine font because for example the Capital "ß" and other stuff. Following to my question, is it possible to set the numbers height on the same height as the text?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
55155TTT       
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some Examples from my thesis, also in my \cite for example [Mar06] it looks strange

[image: Some Examples from my thesis]

Comment: Try out `atbT`. What is the height of the text?

Comment: For example the picture Shows the "T" is taller then "5"

Comment: Yes, but the b is taller than the T, and the t is smaller. Why do you want to change the font design to adapt the numbers to the T and not to one of the other chars?

Comment: i added some examples of my thesis

Comment: That is the decision of the font designer! If you do not like it, use another font.

Comment: you can use the `+case` feature to change the height of the numbers. but it changes other things as well so it may not be something you want to apply throughout the document. Will write a response when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The height of numbers in some fonts tend to be optimised for appearance in normal text which means that they usually are slightly smaller than the height of the upper case glyphs.

This however becomes an issue when these glyphs are surrounded by upper case. Numbers are not the only glyphs that follow that rule, the dash is also on of these glyphs that can require change when surrounded by upper case.

To fix that, some fonts include the `case` feature that will switch to the "upper case" glyphs instead. That feature is probably not to be used throughout your document but can be used sporadically when needed.

Where it becomes a judgement call is then you have these glyphs between an upper and a lower case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Without the \texttt{case} feature:\\
55155TTT, DIN4322, H13, Figure 5\\
CD-ROM or cd-rom\\


With the \texttt{case} feature:\\
{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+case}}%
55155TTT, DIN4322, H13, Figure 5\\
CD-ROM or cd-rom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.