# uppercase numbers in chapter headers and captions

Tags: fonts, numbering, captions, libertine, header

I'm trying to get uppercase numbers for Linux Libertine/Biolinum with PdfLaTeX because Libertine font numbers have a different height than text and I think it doesn't look nice in headers and captions. ([same problem here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489764/libertine-font-numbers-have-a-different-height-than-text))
Is there another way to get uppercase numbers without using `fontspec`? I can't use that because I need to use PdfLaTeX to compile.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize=auto, fontsize = 14pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lf, sflf]{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{section}-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Appendix}  
    \section{Figures}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
        \captionbelow{Default}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: bottom example is what I want with pdflatex]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “uppercase numbers”. The size of the digits in Linux Libertine is a precise design choice.

Comment: I added a picture of what I need. You can use the case feature with fontspec for Libertine, but I can't use fontspec because I want to use pdflatex. See also the Link in the description. Overall the numbers of Libertine are optimized for the use in Text. With the case feature you can have uppercase numbers. But I don't know how to use it with pdflatex.

Comment: Simply put, you can't, unless you regenerate the Type1 fonts from the OpenType version using the higher digits.

Comment: how can i do that? is there no other alternative?

Comment: You could use `otftotfm` to generate `tfm` files while providing an encoding vector with `/one` replaced by `/one.cap` etc. Not a trivial thing to do. Why do you want to use pdftex instead of luatex or xetex?

Comment: @RalfStubner Some time ago I've already converted some fonts with autoinst and otftotfm. So I know how to use that but dont exactly how to generate the files that I need for uppercase numbers. Is there any good instruction how to manage the converting for this specific case? I want to use pdflatex because I use some options of the microtype package I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a **very rough** way of getting cap figures with pdfTeX. Since you are using T1 encoding, I am starting with `ec.enc`:

```
cp $(kpsewhich ec.enc) myec.enc
```

Next edit `myec.enc` to replace `/zero` to `/nine` with `/zero.cap` to `/nine.cap`. Now we call `oftotfm` with this encoding vector:

```
otftotfm -e myec -fliga -fkern $(kpsewhich LinLibertine_R.otf)
```

This outputs a map-line for `pdftex` and creates various TFM and VF files. Finally a simple test using plain TeX:

```
\pdfmapline{LinLibertineO--myec--Fkern--Fliga--base LinLibertineO "AutoEnc_4axnaqv5awcfmflkbhnm6b5u5e ReEncodeFont" <[a_4axnaq.enc <LinLibertineO.pfb}

\font\myfont=LinLibertineO--myec--Fkern--Fliga at 10pt
{\myfont DIN4322 ffi Vo}
\bye
```

Result:

[image]

Of course, you will also need LaTeX integration with FD files etc. See the `otftotfm` man page for details.

Comment: thank you very much, it works great for the the regular libertine font. Now I'm trying to apply this method for LinuxBiolinum Bold, but it doesn't work. I'm using the same myec.enc file with /one.cap etc.  As a result I'm getting bold small numbers. I'm using      
\pdfmapline{LinBiolinumOB--myec--Fkern--Fliga--base LinBiolinumOB "AutoEnc_s7bqtneobpox3hv5uycpl47aqe ReEncodeFont" <[a_s7bqtn.enc <LinBiolinumOB.pfb}                                                       
  \font\mybold=LinBiolinumOB--myec--Fkern--Fliga at 14pt                                    {\mybold DIN4322 ffi Vo}

Comment: In the end I want to use it for captions, sections, chapters etc.

Comment: @Bolle Linux Biolinum does not include these glyphs. You could use Libertinus Sans instead. And mabe Libertinus Serif instead of Linux Libertine.

Comment: it works nicely for specific text parts with libertinus now. But if I want to use it together with the microtype package I get a "pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts". I already updated everything with updmap and mktexlsr, still the same error. How can I avoid that and still use the microtype package?

Comment: @Bolle Can you create a minimal example for this? Possibly in a new question.

Comment: It works fine, the error is coming because of the \pdfmapline code. Because of this code the font is now used in the whole document. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I found the solution in the pdftex manual (page 29). You have to use a modifier character for example \pdfmapline{+LinBiolinumOB....pfb). Otherwise the default
map file pdftex.map will not be read in.

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the font scale automatically and you don't have to define something like \font\SansRegNum=LibertinusSans-Regular--myec--Fkern--Fliga at 12pt (8pt, 9pt etc.)?

Comment: Wait a second. Both `\pdfmapline` and `\font` where meant to show that it works in principle, not as a full solution. As mentioned in the answer, you should write `.fd` files for your font in order to get LaTeX integration. Calling `\pdfmapline` is also not necessary when you create a `.map` file and install that. The man page of otftotfm has more details on both topics.